# Out of scope in function callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

My client "class" looks like this:

```
var Client = (function () {
    function Client(socket)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.country_code = null;

        var that = this;

        this.socket.on('message', function(data) {
            var r = JSON.parse(data);

            switch (r.action) {
                case 'init':
                    that.country_code = r.country_code;

                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    Client.prototype.message_handler = function(data)
    {
    };

    return Client;
})();
```

I'm utilizing websocket.io module to receive messages from clients. Now, the code above works, but I would really like to have the `Client.prototype.message_handler`, so that the ctor would look like this:

```
function Client(socket)
{
    this.socket = socket;
    this.country_code = null;

    this.socket.on('message', this.message_handler);
}
```

However, the problem is that now in the message_handler function

```
Client.prototype.message_handler = function(data)
{
    var r = JSON.parse(data);

    switch (r.action) {
        case 'init':
            this.country_code = r.country_code; // Doesn't work.

            break;
    }
};
```

`this` doesn't resolve to the Client-class. Is there anyway to pass or whatever `this` to the function via `this.socket.on('message', this.message_handler)`? That way, I could use inheritance with different handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Javascript `Function.prototype.bind` feature described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). In your case, you can do this (updated thanks to @nhaa123's fix):

```
this.socket.on('message', this.message_handler.bind(this));
```

Then the socket's message handler will always be bound to the Client instance.

Comment: Thanks, but won't work. console.log(this.country_code) inside message_handler still gives undefined... E: Got it: this.socket.on('message', this.message_handler.bind(this));

Comment: I'll update my answer so other people see something that works there, but I am confused about why the old version didn't work. Hmm...